# .NetCore MVC Application - Jquery date set in Create view is reset in Edit View

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker, asp.net-mvc-views

As per the title, in my CRUD application, the date set in the Create View (via Jquery datepicker) is not remembered when I edit records.

[image]

Here is my code for the DOB field in my Create View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>

        <p><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
```

Here is my code for the DOB field in my Edit View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>

        <p><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
```

The Edit (get) Method does seem to have the correct DOB before it passes the entity to the view:

[image]

I am unsure how to sort of pass values through.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks